# Clicking through absolute positioned divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the autocomplete js from here:

https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/demo.html

It all works fine but when I click one of the suggestions

[image: Suggestions]

A click event fires on the body element which then shuts down the whole drop down menu.
(this is by design as in every other case where there body is genuinely clicked I want the drop down menu to disappear)

When I check the event that is firing on the body the path is showing that it is starting at the body element. I have put event stop propogation functions on all of the divs created in the drop down menue including the ones created by the autocomplete. It doesn't seem to be coming from them - it is if it the click is firing the click event of the suggestions divs but additionally of body underneath as an entirely separate click event.

How can I stop this from happening?

Many thanks.

SOLUTION:

The autocomplete javascript code from pixabay was capturing the mousedown event - and then setting the display of the suggestions to none. This meant that when the click event fired the suggestion div was no longer there causing it to fire a click on whatever was underneath the click. So I changed the mousedown event in the autocomplete code to click and this has fixed the problem.

This seems like a bug in their code? I can't see a reason why you'd ever want the click event to be fired on what happens to be underneath a suggestion?

Comment: Can you share the code for your propagation functions?

Comment: Its difficult because they are peppered through out the code - i have put them everywhere. But the point is - the event is coming from  a bubbling up. It is firing on the body itself - the stop propogation are working.

Comment: Can you share the html of the these divs?

Comment: <div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-val="ActionScript"><b>A</b>ctionScript</div>

Comment: Worked it out - see edit above.

Thanks for your help - in an indirect way I wouldn't have been able to solve it without your promptings.